# Fetching json api data in volley with conditions

Tags: android, android-volley

I am fetching an url using volley in my android project. Everything is fine. The json data from the api gives `localteam_id` and `visitorteam_id`. Below is my json volley request.

```
final String TEAM_ID = "688";

    String fixturesURL = url;

    JsonObjectRequest leagueRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            fixturesURL, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    //Log.d("Fixtures", response.toString());
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("data");
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject data  = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            //Log.d("Fixtures", data.getString("id"));

                            String localteamID = data.getString("localteam_id");
                            String visitorteamID = data.getString("visitorteam_id");
                            String opponentID = "";
```

Problem here is I need to fetch the opponent team name again with the id. Here the opponent may be localteam_id or else visitorteam_id. I tried with some if conditions it's not working. Help me.

Comment: can you post your logcat and the response of the volley?

Comment: Your team only help you, how can we get to know about what the conditions your team has put for it

Comment: Your question is not clear, Edit your question in a  manner so that we can understand what issue you're facing and let us know what you have tried so far to achieve it.

Comment: Either localteamId or visitorteamid is "688" from the api json data. Here I want to assign the id which is not "688" is equal to the opponentID string. From the JSONArray for some object localid = "688" and for some object visitorid = "688"